# trying to set Vary header in htaccess

Tags: apache, http-headers

mod_header is installed and I tried putting this in htaccess but the header info does not change. any ideas?

Header append Vary: User-Agent

Answer (score 0):

Is the syntax correct here? From: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header

```
Header [condition] set|append|merge|add|unset|echo|edit header [value] [replacement] [early|env=[!]variable]
```

It looks like you don't have enough arguments.